# nginx config - forward http to https, forward www.domain.tld to domain.tld and two subdomains

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to configure nginx to:

```
http://www.domain.tld --> https://domain.tld
http://domain.tld --> https://domain.tld
http://api.domain.tld --> https://api.domain.tld
```

The 'www'-webroot serves static HTML (AngularJS) and the API serves an Node.JS app that should 'upstream' from localhost:3000. I guess I'm in the right direction, however it doesn't seem to work for me. Here's what I've got so far:

```
upstream api_server {
    server              localhost:3000;
    keepalive           64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name         api.domain.tld;
    return 301          https://api.domain.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name         *.domain.tld www.domain.tld;
    return 301          https://domain.tld$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name         api.domain.tld;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/ssl_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ssl_key.key;
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

location / {
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass          http://api_server/;
    proxy_redirect      off;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name         *.domain.tld www.domain.tld;

    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/ssl_cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/ssl_key.key;
    ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    root /var/www/webroot/;
}
```

Right now this is all in my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/domain.tld.conf` file.

<del>Any help would be really appreciated.</del>

---

***EDIT:***

***I've figured it out myself (a bit of help from Tan Hong Tat), so the example is updated.***

***If you've got any improvements please do tell, I'll update it.***

Comment: Probably usefull to say I've used some template from the nginx site, but maybe that's my error to begin with. But nginx reload says 'OK'...

Answer (score 1):

Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in the server block for HTTP. Remove the `listen 80` in the HTTPS server block.

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name         domain.tld www.domain.tld;
        return 301          https://domain.tld$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name         api.domain.tld;
        return 301          https://api.domain.tld$request_uri;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name         domain.tld www.domain.tld api.domain.tld;

        location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header        Connection "";
            proxy_http_version      1.1;
            proxy_cache             one;
            proxy_cache_key         sfs$request_uri$scheme;
            proxy_pass              http://domain_tld_api_server;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work exactly as I wanted to, but it got met in the right direction of thinking. Thanks for the fast reply!